# Limit the translation to just one word in a phrase?

Tags: regex, perl

Coming new to Perl world from Python, and wonder if there is a simple way to limit the *translation* or *replace* to just one word in a phrase?

In the example, the 2nd word ***k**ind* also got changed to ***l**ind*.  Is there a simple way to do the translation without diving into some *looping*?   Thanks.

The first word has been correctly translated to *gazelle*, but 2nd word has been changed too as you can see.

```
my $string = 'gazekke is one kind of antelope';

my $count = ($string =~ tr/k/l/);

print "There are $count changes \n";

print $string;         # gazelle is one lind of antelope    <-- kind becomes lind too!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an option for `tr` to stop translation after the first word.
But you can use a regex with backreferences for this.

```
use strict;

my $string = 'gazekke is one kind of antelope';

# Match first word in $1 and rest of sentence in $2.
$string =~ m/(\w+)(.*)/;

# Translate all k's to l's in the first word.
(my $translated = $1) =~ tr/k/l/;

# Concatenate the translated first word with the rest
$string = "$translated$2";

print $string;
```

Outputs: `gazelle is one kind of antelope`

Answer (score 2):

Pick the first match (a word in this case), precisely what regex does when without `/g`, and in that word replace all wanted characters, by running code in the replacement side, by `/e`

```
$string =~ s{(\w+)}{ $1 =~ s/k/l/gr }e;
```

In the regex in the replacement side, `/r` modifier makes it handily return the changed string and doesn't change the original, what also allows a substitution to run on `$1` (which can't be modified as is a read-only).

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is a character class transliterator.  For anything else you would use regex.

`$string =~ s/gazekke/gazelle/;`

You can put a code block as the second half of `s///` to do more complicated replacements or transmogrifications.

`$string =~ s{([A-Za-z]+)}{ &mangler($1) if $should_be_mangled{$1}; }ge;`

Edit:
Here's how you would first locate a phrase and then work on it.

```
$phrase_regex = qr/(?|(gazekke) is one kind of antelope|(etc))/;
$string =~ s{($phrase_regex)}{
  my $match = $1;
  my $word = $2;
  $match =~ s{$word}{
    my $new = $new_word_map{$word};
    &additional_mangling($new);
    $new;
  }e;
  $match;
}ge;
```

Here's the Perl regex documentation.
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre

Comment: Thanks!  I do know the difference between *tr* vs. *s*.  The question/challenge is to handle a phrase, not a single word.

Comment: Can you expand on that?  If you need to pick out a phrase and then pick out a word to change, you can do that by nesting the regexes.